# How to deploy a spring boot restful API with Azure pipeline

Tags: mysql, spring, azure, azure-pipelines

I have spring boot application that is connected to a mysql database. I have a repo in Azure Repo and a pipeline in Azure Pipeline. On Azure Portal I have made a Azure Mysql database and also a web app. How do I connect the web app and the pipeline? I thought I already connected them as I made the pipeline. I can't seem to be able to use my api as i get 404 back when calling it. All tutorials are focusing on how to deploy without the pipeline but that is not my case. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @David Larsson Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any question.

Answer (score 0):

Beside what you have done above you also need to do below steps

1, First you need to create service connection to connect your azure subscription to your azure devops pipeline. Please check the detailed steps [Sign in to Azure Pipelines and connect to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java-webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=java-tomcat#sign-in-to-azure-pipelines-and-connect-to-azure).

2, When you have your pipeline. You also need to [customize your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops) to build your java app with maven task or other build tasks. Please check [Build Java apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java?view=azure-devops) for more information.

3, You also need to use [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops)(in the release pipeline or build pipeline) to deploy your app to azure web app.

There is a [tutorial](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/tomcat/) provided by Microsoft with detailed steps to deploy java app to azure.